# Spring 4 @Autowire not binding correctly?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I m trying to Autowire a bean to a implementation but it returns a null pointer Exception.

```
package org.com.api;

public interface Multiply {
    public int multipler(int a, int b);
}

package org.com.core;
import org.com.api.Multiply;

public class MultiplyImpA implements Multiply {
    public int multipler(int a, int b){
        return a*b;
    }
}

package org.com.core;
import org.com.api.Multiply;
public class MultiplyImpB implements Multiply {
    public int multipler(int a, int b){
        int total = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i <=b; i++){
            total += a;
        }
        return total;
    }
}

package org.com.Service;
import org.com.api.Multiply;
public Calculator {
    @Autowire
    private Multiply multiply;
    public int calcMultiply(int a, int b){
        return multiply.multipler(a,b);
    }
}
```

In my applicationContext.xml I  have added the following

```
<bean id="multiply" class="org.com.core.MultiplyImpA" scope="prototype"/>
```

Now in runtime I get a NullPointerExpection. multiply is null.

for testing purpose I tried this. It works, I understand here I m explicitly getting the Bean. So this means the autowire didnt work ? is there something I m missing ?

```
Multiply m = (Multiply)factory.getBean("multiply");
System.out.println(m.multiplier(2,4);
```

Comment: Post your spring.xml.

Comment: Yes, spring.xml please. How do you instantiate the `Calculator`?

Comment: Right now I m calling from a junit test case.

Comment: updated my answer. If it does not solve your problem post the unit test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you have a typo in your bean xml.

Instead of

```
<bean id="multiply" class="package org.com.core.MultiplyImpA" scope="prototype"/>
```

it should be (using the full qualified classname only)

```
<bean id="multiply" class="org.com.core.MultiplyImpA" scope="prototype"/>
```

**EDIT:**

Possible error could be that the `Calculator` class is not managed by spring. Instantiating the class using the `new` operator would fail because there is no way that spring would get a reference to inject the collaborator:

```
Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
calculator.calcMultiply(1, 2); // would throw a NPE because the `Multiply` instance (in your case `MultiplyImpA`) has not been injected.
```

So instead instantiate the `Calculator` class using spring:

```
<bean id="calculator" class="org.com.service.Calculator"/>
<bean id="multiply" class="org.com.core.MultiplyImpA"/>
```

Retrieve it through the application-context:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
Calculator calculator = ctx.getBean(Calculator.class);
```

Spring would then manage the dependencies by scanning the `@Autowired` annotation, looking at the field type and trying to find a qualified bean from the application context.

Comment: The typo is only here not in my actual program. thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: It didnt work. ApplocationContext complained it had two types of implementations, Then  I removed implemntationB bean from applicationContext, thought it would work but it wont still work.

Comment: Then please post your full application-context xml and the unit test/or code snippet that bootstraps the application. Otherwise it will be difficult to help.

Comment: "expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency" was the error message I m getting when running the test. This is an example of the scenario I m trying  in my application. I will try to post them.

Comment: I think I found the issue, Guess it was totally un related and thanks for explaining @Autowired.

Answer (score 1):

Autowiring resolves by type, since there are two different impl, you need to use qualifier to narrow it down. SO try the below.

```
public Calculator {
@Autowire
@Qualifier("multiply")
private Multiply multiply ;
public int calcMultiply(int a, int b){
    return multiply.multipler(a,b);
}
}
```

Comment: I tried this already. It didn't help. I could n't figure why multiply is still null?